# Custom JS Cursor - How to limit staggered circles array length to prevent individuals showing on fast movements?

Tags: javascript, animation, geometry, cursor, stroke

This is a tricky one, I found this [awesome cursor](https://codepen.io/zainzafar/pen/KKejxQg) that mimics an ink brush but there is a catch, if you move your mouse fast enough the trick is uncovered and the illusion breaks since the multiple circles of which the cursor is made take some time to reunite all together because they're staggered by the same factor.

I'm looking for a solution to limit the array distancing at high mouse movement speeds to a continuous "stroke" to keep the brush illusion from breaking without the user noticing it's an artifact.

Been looking within the `mousemove` event and found that the API exports **movementX** and **movementY** that represent the delta of the previous cursor point and the subsequent landing one, kinda giving a unit of measure for the strength of the inertia with which the mouse is moved.

But I haven't been able to patch it within the code to achieve the desired result, I just came to the conclusion that both **movementX** and **movementY** need to have a smaller value than +-15 ([on Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/movementX)) to avoid circles from detaching too much from the continuous stroke.

I also tried to diminish the factor of the last values within the `forEach()` loop as so:

```js
x += (nextCircle.x - x) * 0.1; // changed from 0.3
y += (nextCircle.y - y) * 0.1; // changed from 0.3
```

This indeed made the illusion more solid but also the staggering animation faster (less impressive and less noticeable) and individual circles can still be seen on fast left-right dashes of the mouse cursor.

Wondering if there is a solution that implies less calculus to save computing, it's just a cursor after all.

How would you approach it?

```js
const coords = { x: 0, y: 0 };
const circles = document.querySelectorAll(".circle");

const cursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");

circles.forEach(function (circle, index) {
  circle.x = 0;
  circle.y = 0;
  circle.style.backgroundColor = "white";
});

window.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
  coords.x = e.clientX;
  coords.y = e.clientY;
});

function animateCircles() {
  let x = coords.x;
  let y = coords.y;

  cursor.style.top = x;
  cursor.style.left = y;
  
  circles.forEach(function (circle, index) {
    circle.style.left = x - 12 + "px";
    circle.style.top = y - 12 + "px";

    circle.style.scale = (circles.length - index) / circles.length;

    circle.x = x;
    circle.y = y;

    const nextCircle = circles[index + 1] || circles[0];
    x += (nextCircle.x - x) * 0.3;
    y += (nextCircle.y - y) * 0.3;
  });

  requestAnimationFrame(animateCircles);
}

animateCircles();
```

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100vh;
}

.cursor {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 0;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999999999999999;  
}

.circle {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<h2>Hello World</h2>
<div class="cursor">
  
<div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```